# Converting image/array list for keras input R

Tags: r, keras, cimg

I intend to feed neural net with image data. Originally I have them stored as a list of arrays with dims 10,10,3 (height, length, color channel).

1. Does anyone know how to convert the list containing multiple cimg images into one cimg storing multiple images in R?

and/or

2. Does anyone know how to convert list of arrays with dims 10,10,3 into the object acceptable by keras?

Comment: Are the cimg(s) in the list named or just [10,10,3] arrays in a list?

Comment: They may be named or not (initially were named, for indexing & filtering purposes, however I can always set names(list) <- NULL

Comment: Does the approach below work for your purposes?

Comment: @Chris yes, it does, thank you very much. However I had also to use aperm() function to flip my array.

Comment: Why was that necessary (flipping) and what was the desired/resulting dim(arr)?

Comment: Flipping was necessary to adjust the array dims to the vector with labels. The input array dims should have following order: observations, height, width, channels. If it does not, then keras throws an error.

Comment: Understood, and thanks for updating on input requirements. So that this discussion of `keras` and images provides useful info to future searchers who may not read comments, I suggest you write up your process as an answer and then accept it as generally questions with answers are navigated to first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `simplify2array`, which takes a list and returns an array.

```
my_images_arr <- simplify2array(my_list_of_cimg)
```

there after, make your data labels. `keras` doesn't appear to require that your array object have a `class` attribute, just be in a consistent form, in this case an array of images.